# disable outlook VSTO plugin icon

Tags: outlook

I have requirement to disable outlook vsto plugin icon if user open email from saved location . its job is to select highlighted emails from outlook and saved to external crm . There is new requirement that if email is saved on disk and re opened again it still shows the outlook plugin incon , i have to disable the incon if email is opened from disk . 
any idea how to achieve this . I user select any email from outlook it should be fine but if email is saved on disk outlook addin icon should be disabled.
Many thanks

Comment: So what are you havign problems with? Making your ribbon button disabled or invisible? Or figuring out if the current message was created on top of an MSG file?

Comment: my problem is when opening saved outlook email from disk should not display outlook plugin my bespoke one because its letting users to save those emails to external platform .

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, mail items opened from the disk don't have the EntryID property set. I'd suggest starting from the [NewInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspectors.newinspector) event which is fired whenever a new inspector window is opened, either as a result of user action or through program code. So, you may check whether the `EntryID` exists and whether item is not composed one which means newly created in Outlook. The `PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS` property provides flags that can be used to identify whether it is read-only or composed item.

As for the Fluent UI, you need to use the [IRibbonUI.Invalidate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidate?view=office-pia) or [IRibbonUI.InvalidateControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidatecontrol?view=office-pia) methods. You can customize the Ribbon UI by using callback procedures in COM add-ins. For each of the callbacks the add-in implements, the responses are cached. For example, if an add-in writer implements the `getImage` callback procedure for a button, the function is called once, the image loads, and then if the image needs to be updated, the cached image is used instead of recalling the procedure. This process remains in-place until the add-in signals that the cached values are invalid by using the `Invalidate` method, at which time, the callback procedure is again called and the return response is cached. The add-in can then force an immediate update of the UI by calling the Refresh method. The `getVisible` callback should be used for hiding and displaying the ribbon UI dynamically.

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is described in-depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)